# Is there a way to save a mac terminal output directly to a file?

Tags: excel, macos, terminal

I am carrying out a research project for which I need to do quite a lot of calculations. I basically calculated a lot of features for structures present in a .sdf file. I automated the entire process and carried it out in the terminal of my mac.

The thing is, there are over 48 rows and about 1500 columns. Manually typing in the data to an excel sheet would be a very strenuous task. I was wondering whether there was any way to directly save all the data into an excel sheet or not.

Whether it is sorted out or not does not matter. I think that the effort put into sorting a file will be quite less than manually making one.

It is being outputted as numbers separated by an indentation. For example,

```
(9613791)   2.69174 4.00454 4.2916  6.25497 6.65652 6.5094  5.18009 5.15649 5.823377.19567  8.21786 6.99439 16.2414 30.3753 30.6785 32.3146 30.0467 51.6735 25.142149.4748  51.7923 42.1594 52.7151 36.7925 1385.6  2004.66 2277.51 2055.07 2273.911577.31  996.44  2300.92 1986.91 1913.57 1486.7  2496.63 2.45285 3.78492 4.502884.55984  2.82045 2.75078 1.31798 4.53201 4.57725 3.39381 2.39053 3.80041 

(6326464)   6.14815 5.46639 4.81788 6.00802 10.6837 8.52504 7.72782 8.05056 8.8713412.2334  12.8092 7.97405 20.3998 18.8032 25.2747 31.2464 33.5688 42.0236 25.741528.9837  33.9351 40.8985 47.1114 31.8816 752.681 1090.84 1049.61 953.366 1405.21942.868  876.854 1345.75 1178.31 1467.03 1395.57 1371.48 2.67685 3.35145 5.508316.20868  5.91418 4.43033 3.44952 6.23538 5.99355 6.30963 7.03768 6.14026 `
```

Note: This just a small snippet of the actual output. I could not post the image until I got 10 points. I need to get the data between the two numbers that I put a bracket between in one row. The next row starts from the second number that is between the brackets. There are basically around 1500 columns of such data. As suggested by @deceze in a comment, I will try to alter my program to implement a function that automatically save the data. But is there an alternative method that can help me expedite the process without trying to make changes to my program?

Comment: How is it being output exactly? In some format which can easily/automatically be turned into a spreadsheet? Can you alter the program that produces this output to output either CSV or directly XLS data...?

Comment: @deceze I'll add the method in the details. I'll try to do that, but just in case it doesn't, what should I do?

Comment: there is a way saving all your output to text file. just add .txt at end of line of your command as **myFolder/filename.txt** you would receive all your screen content in file and in easy to copy formate. Might this be helpful.. give it a try

Comment: @Akkikodwani I have used that. But I would specifically like something that automatically saves it to a csv or xls file because I need to run some calculations on this data using another program that I have written. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: try using tee command followed by the location of the csv file as **ifconfig | tee  ~/ifconfig.csv** is it helpful

Comment: do you have access to the code that generates that output?  can you modify the code to add in "\t" tab characters?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes. The program is custom made. I cannot, however, release the code because it is part of a research project and I would like to keep it confidential. I'm trying to make appropriate edits to the program so that I get the desired output, but I'm searching for alternatives too

Comment: You don't need to release the code or make it public, although I don't see any confidentiality violation if you list one or two lines from your app... the ones that do fprintf or fout or whatever line that prints out the digits into stdout.  You yourself would be making that modification to add in tab characters into the format string of the code.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I see. Anyway, I got that sorted out an hour ago using sort of the logic that you have listed. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine your mysterious program is called `fred` and you run it by typing

```
./fred
```

in the Terminal. Now, you can make the output get sent into a file called `file.txt` by running it like this:

```
./fred > file.txt
```

Now, you can copy the first 10 lines of the file by running this command:

```
head -10 file.txt | pbcopy
```

and then click `edit` under your question and paste (with Command-V) those first 10 lines in so we can see what you are talking about.

If you just want the first number of every line in that file put into a `CSV` file called `lovely.csv` you can do this:

```
awk '{print $1}' file.txt > lovely.csv
```

If you want the 9th column from every line, change the `$1` above to `$9`.

If you want the 1st, 2nd and 4th field, use

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$4}' file.txt > lovely.cv
```

Comment: I got that sorted out. Thanks for the help

Comment: No probs - glad to be of assistance. If you get stuck, just ask a new question - questions are free :-)